# Intersect 2 columns in data.table R

Tags: r

i have a data table as this  example below:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a,b,c,d | a,c,d |
| r,h,g | r |

so each column of this table contain a list. I wanted to create 2 other list in 2 different columns, each one represent the intersect or union of col1 and 2:

the output that I want is this one :

| col1 | col2 | inter | union |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a,b,c | a,c,d,k | a,c | a,b,c,d,k |
| r,h,g | r | r | r,h,g |

I tried this command but it gives me an error:

```
data$inter = intersect(data$col1, data$col2)
```

the error is :

```
Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Supplied 4 items to be assigned to 748 items of column 'intersect'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code
```

FYI: its not the real data, its just a simplify example, the error that I am showing is for the real data

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this command, and it seems working :

```
mapply(function(x, y) paste0(intersect(x, y), collapse = " "), strsplit(data$col1, '\\s'), strsplit(data$col2, '\\s'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

1. You should convert your elements into vectors. As is, the functions `intersect` and `union` won't work on single strings.
2. You should work with columns as lists and use a `rowwise` computation to achieve your results.

```r
library(tidyverse)
apply(data, c(1, 2), \(x) strsplit(x, ",")[[1]]) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(inter = list(intersect(col1, col2)),
         union = list(union(col1, col2)))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Rowwise: 
  col1      col2      inter     union    
  <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <chr [4]> <chr [3]> <chr [3]> <chr [4]>
2 <chr [3]> <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [3]>
```

You can get back to your original string-like dataframe by using `paste` over all columns:

```r
... %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), paste, collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Rowwise: 
  col1    col2  inter union  
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 a,b,c,d a,c,d a,c,d a,b,c,d
2 r,h,g   r     r     r,h,g
```